# Artemis (ActiveMQ) messaging in Wildfly 10 cluster (domain)

Tags: wildfly, cluster-computing, activemq-artemis

Could someone provide an example of messaging application working under Wildfly 10 cluster (domain)? We are struggling with it and given that it is a new technology, there is a terrible lack of resources.

Currently we have the following:

A domain consisting of two hosts (nodes) and three groups on each, i.e. six separate servers in the domain.

A relevant part of **server configuration** (in domain.xml):

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
            <server name="default">
                <security enabled="false"/>
                <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password}"/>
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" delete-non-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" consume="true" send="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <address-setting name="#" redistribution-delay="1000" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" page-size-bytes="2097152" max-siz
                <http-connector name="http-connector" endpoint="http-acceptor" socket-binding="http"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                <broadcast-group name="bg-group1" connectors="http-connector" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster" jgroups-stack="tcphq"/>
                <discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster" jgroups-stack="tcphq"/>
                <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" discovery-group="dg-group1" connector-name="http-connector" address="jms"/>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                <jms-queue name="TestQ" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/testq"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" reconnect-attempts="-1" block-on-acknowledge="true" ha="true" entries="java
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="xa" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" co
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

The configuration is more or less default, except added *TestQ* queue.

*tcphq* stack is defined in the JGroups configuration as follows:

```
                <stack name="tcphq">
                    <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-hq"/>
                    <protocol type="TCPPING">
                        <property name="initial_hosts">
                          dev1[7660],dev1[7810],dev1[7960],dev2[7660],dev2[7810],dev2[7960]
                        </property>
                        <property name="port_range">
                            0
                        </property>
                    </protocol>
                    <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                    <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-hq-fd"/>
                    <protocol type="FD"/>
                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                    <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                    <protocol type="MFC"/>
                    <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
                </stack>
```

I have written a testing application consisting from a simple "server", meaning MDB and a client as follows:

**Server (MDB):**

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "test", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/testq"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class MessageServer implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        try {
            ObjectMessage msg = null;

            if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                msg = (ObjectMessage) message;
            }
            System.out.print("The number in the message: "+ msg.getIntProperty("count"));
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MessageServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ClientBean implements ClientBeanLocal {

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory factory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/testq")
    private Queue queue;

    @PostConstruct
    public void sendMessage() {

        Connection connection = null;
        try {

            connection = factory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

            Message message = session.createObjectMessage();
            message.setIntProperty("count", 1);

            producer.send(message);
            System.out.println("Message sent.");

        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClientBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It actually works well if both client and server reside in the same group. In such a case it even seems it communicates between hosts (nodes). However if the server and client are in different groups, MDB is not invoked. Moreover, it even seems that MDB is invoked only if it resides in the group with 0 offset. When I moved the server MDB into a different group, it was not responding even if the client was in the same group.

I am a bit confused about JMS in Wildfly 10. There is a lot of examples and materials for older versions with HornetQ, however very few for Artemis. Could someone help? Many thanks.

Comment: Well, I found myself here in search of how to configure the subsystem `jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0` to connect to a remote ActiveMQ server. Any idea?

Comment: Did any of you actually solved this? As we're stumbling about a similiar issue currently and my guess is: if your deployment sits on a different server-group it actually sits on a different instance of wildfly - it feels like it has to be handled somehow through remoting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

As I came with the same question - put the answer that works for me.

Actually as [Miroslav answered on developer.jboss.org](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/268441#952788) the first thing to be checked is `socket-binding` for the `"jgroups-tcp-hq"` and the `port-offset` config on each server.
Should be `<socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-hq" ... port="7600"/>` and `port-offset` is set (e.g. with the `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset` property)  to 60 on *dev1[7660]* server ; 210 on *dev1[7810]* ; 360 on *dev1[7960]*. Same for *dev2* servers.

And the second is `jboss.bind.address.private` property.
Usually default jgroups `socket-binding` refers to the `"private"` interface, e.g.

```
<socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-hq" interface="private" port="7600"/>
```

**So `"private"` interface address must be provided with the `jboss.bind.address.private` property** (e.g. `jboss.bind.address.private=dev1` ) - **otherwise ClusterConnectionBridge will not be established between nodes!**
[See also this post for more details.](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/272517)

If communication between ActiveMQ server instances is established then the log entry must appear in server.log: `AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@63549ead [name=sf.my-cluster ...] is connected.`
[See also this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611384/clustered-wildfly-10-domain-messaging/48322367#48322367)