# Clustered WildFly 10 domain messaging

Tags: jms, cluster-computing, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have three machines located in different networks:

- as-master
- as-node-1
- as-node-2

In as-master I have WildFly as domain host-master and the two nodes have WildFly as domain host-slave each starting an instance in the full-ha server group. From the as-master web console I can see the two nodes in the full-ha profile runtime and if I deploy a WAR it gets correctly started on both nodes.

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is messaging between the two instances of the WAR, i.e. sending a message from a producer instance in as-node-1, consumers in all the nodes should receive the message.

This is what I tried: added a topic to WildFly `domain.xml`:

```
<jms-topic name="MyTopic" entries="java:/jms/my-topic"/>
```

Create a JAX-RS endpoint to trigger a producer bound to the topic:

```
@Path("jms")
@RequestScoped
public class MessageEndpoint {

    @Inject
    JMSContext context;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/jms/my-topic")
    Topic myTopic;

    @GET
    public void sendMessage() {
         this.context.createProducer().send(this.myTopic, "Hello!");
    }

}
```

Create a MDB listening to the topic:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(
        propertyName = "destination",
        propertyValue = "java:/jms/my-topic"
    ),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(
        propertyName = "destinationType",
        propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic")
    )
)
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = /* ... */

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            String body = message.getBody(String.class)
            LOGGER.info("Received message: " + body);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

But when I `curl as-node-1/jms` I see the log only in as-node-1, and when I `curl as-node-2/jms` I see the log only in as-node-2.

Shouldn't the message be delivered on all the nodes where the WAR is deployed? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've come with the exactly same question - put the answer here.

Yes, messages should be delivered to all nodes if a destination is a *Topic*.

With the default configuration ActiveMQ Artemis uses broadcast to discover and connect to other ActiveMQ instances on other nodes (within the same discovery-group):

```
<discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-channel="activemq-cluster"/>
<cluster-connection name="my-cluster" discovery-group="dg-group1" connector-name="http-connector" address="jms"/>
```

Still need to ensure that a JNDI name for a jms-topic starts with the "*jms*" to match the `address="jms"` in the line above (what is OK in your case: "`java:/jms/my-topic`")

**The only thing missed in your example to get it working on all nodes is :
`<cluster password="yourPassword" user="activemqUser"/>`** 

(for sure `activemqUser` user must be added earlier, e.g. with the addUser.sh script).

This let ActiveMQ instances to communicate each other. So called *Core Bridge* connection is created between nodes. As stated in [ActiveMQ manual](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/clusters.html) :

> ..this is done transparently behind the scenes - you don't have to
>   declare an explicit bridge for each node

If everything is OK then the bridge may be found in server.log: `AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@63549ead [name=sf.my-cluster ...] is connected.`

Btw, if a destination is a *Queue* then ActiveMQ will not send a message to other nodes unless a message is not consumed locally.

P.s. as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454512/how-to-distribute-an-event-to-all-nodes-in-a-wildfly-cluster) this refers to a classic approach to distribute an event to all nodes in a cluster.